# Data for droppdown doesn't populate when using Entity Framework ToListAsync() Blazor Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, blazor

In my Blazor server application I have a Blazor component that uses a second component...inside the second component I call a service method that uses entity framework to get a list of 'sites'. If I use 'await' and 'async' for all calls, the dropdown list doesn't get any values. If I change the entity farmwork call to ToList() from ToListAsync(), it does work.

Location.razor

```
@page "/LocationTest"

<TelerikForm Model="ParentObj">
      <FormItems>
        <LocationPicker curLocation="_loc"></LocationPicker>
    </FormItems>
</TelerikForm>

@code
{
    public ParentObj parentobjt = new ParentObj();
    public Location _loc = new();
}
```

LocationPicker.razor

```
@inject DataService dataservice

@using System.Collections.ObjectModel


<FormGroup LabelText="Location" Columns="1" ColumnSpacing="15px">     


        <FormItem>
            <Template>
                <label for="Site">Site:</label>
                <TelerikDropDownList @bind-Value="curLocation.SiteID" DefaultText="Choose a Site" Data="SiteListDropDownValues" Id="ddsite" TextField="Name" ValueField="ID">
                    <DropDownListSettings>
                        <DropDownListPopupSettings Height="auto" />
                    </DropDownListSettings>

                </TelerikDropDownList>
            </Template>
        </FormItem>

</FormGroup>

@code
{
    
    [Parameter]
    public Location curLocation { get; set; } 
    
protected IEnumerable<Site> SiteListDropDownValues { get; set; }

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
SiteListDropDownValues = await matchservice.GetActiveSites();
}
```

GetActiveSites (in DataService)

```
public async Task<List<Site>> GetActiveSites()
        {
            return await _repo.GetActiveSites();
        }
```

GetActiveSites (in _repo)

```
   public async Task<List<Site>> GetActiveSites()
        {
           using (var ctx = _matchDBContext.CreateDbContext())
                { 
                 return await ctx.Sites.
                        Where(active => active.Active.Equals(true)).
                        Where(del => del.Deleted.Equals(false)).
                        OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToListAsync();
                }

            }
```

When I run all of that, the dropdown has no values. If I change the ToListAsync() in GetActiveSites() to ToList() and remove the await ...the dropdownlist gets values....

Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: Does DataService use an Interface and if so, is the method signature in the Interface the same including the return type? I would think it would have to be, but just doublechecking. Also, not sure why you are using WHERE twice instead of using && in one WHERE clause.

Comment: The data service does not use an interface. The method names match and the return types match. Regarding the multiple where clauses....no reason. :)